# What could stop an app from executing on Windows 10 Home with "Windows cannot find <path to executable>"?

Tags: windows, windows-10, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

I'm having an issue with a Windows 10 Home workstation where Acrobat Reader DC refuses to open.

Initially I uninstalled it and then reinstalled it and had the same error. I then used the Acrobat Reader cleaner utility and then reinstalled Acrobat Reader again, but the same error occurred.

Here's the error:
[image: acrobat reader error]

After this I renamed `C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe` to an arbitrary name and Acrobat Reader DC opened right up without a hiccup.

When I renamed the .exe back, same failure.

**Any idea of what could cause this?** I'm not finding a kill list in the registry with this so far, so I'm really scratching my head as to what could cause such behavior.

Comment: "Any idea of what could cause this?" - Group policy blocking a specific executable.

Comment: On a Home system @Ramhound? That's pretty crazy, but interesting... Hard to get into that without some hacking.

Comment: How are you opening it? You need to start there. If this a shortcut, then where does that shortcut point? It’s not likely it points to the path you gave, because it works when you rename the file. That means most likely there is another installation of acrord32.exe in your path somewhere. That is the one opening when you rename the file.

Comment: @Appleoddity in any way. It fails in this manner by going to the direct path and starting it there. It fails like this when executing from the shell. It fails the same by using the shortcut that is indeed pointing to the correct path. Conversely it succeeds when renamed and any accompanying call is made to the renamed file.

Comment: So @Ramhound I managed to install `gpedit.msc` from [this URL](https://www.itechtics.com/enable-gpedit-windows-10-home/), however I'm a little nervous of the reliability of the resource. I guess it's alright because I didn't really detect an infection and was able to execute it at `c:\Windows\SysWOW64\gpedit.msc` without any perceivable problems. What should I be hunting for since there's no search option?

Comment: You failed to mention you were using Windows 10 Home.

Comment: In any event this is an indication your user profile is corrupt.  Create a new user and see if still exhibits the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately creating a fresh account yields the same result @Ramhound, so it is not profile corruption...

Comment: Ok. So I misunderstood. You’re renaming the file and running it from something like file explorer, and it works? But not if it has the original name? This type of thing would  typically be something intercepting access to the file, like an anti-virus. It could be a restriction like suggested by @ramhound, but unlikely I think. I would take a look at any low level products that might be blocking access to the file, like a security product.

Comment: @Appleoddity right, unfortunately there're no low level apps that could do this. I've uninstalled & disabled them all. It definitely seems to be some kind of a policy specific to some apps. I did see another identical behavior w/ Malwarebytes, but after renaming it and running it, it resolved an issue with itself during scan (I was left with the impression that it was a registry entry or policy, but can't recall the details as I wasn't scrutinizing it upon completion). Thought I was done, but after I tried to start AcroRd32 this strangeness reared its head again. No other apps seem to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check the contents of your Image File Execution Options registry key. Programs can be blocked from running with an appropriate entry in that key. There's an explanation at https://blog.malwarebytes.com/101/2015/12/an-introduction-to-image-file-execution-options/

Comment: Thank you. Spot on. It turns out that Avast did something horrible and even deactivating or uninstallation doesn't seem to resolve it. I'm finding essentially what this person notes [here](https://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=209981.0). Avast has inserted `"C:\Program Files (x86)\AVAST Software\Avast Cleanup\autoreactivator.exe"` into the `Debugger` field.